# Setting up Server to Receive App Store Notifications

Tags: ios, server, app-store-connect

I have created my ios app and in the process of submitting it to the AppStore.  I come across this:

> URL for App Store Server Notifications

Can someone tell me how I would set up a server to ONLY receive app store notifications on my Macbook pro?

Answer (score 0):

You should have your computer connected to a public IP, with something that behaves like a web server, compliant with the requirements that Apple needs.

You can read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/enabling_app_store_server_notifications